# Javascript array push not working, alert is not show

Tags: javascript

I have make like this an function, that is working but it is not working

```
            combine_subject =[];
        function combine_subject(va)
        {

          if(va.checked==true)
             {
                    combine_subject.push(va.id);
                    setTimeout(function(){$(va).attr('class','select');},100);  }
            else
            {
                var itemtoRemove = va.id ; 
                combine_subject.splice($.inArray(itemtoRemove,combine_subject),1);
                setTimeout(function(){$(v).parent().attr('class','active');},100);
             } 
             alert(combine_subject);
        }
```

Comment: You are having same function and variable name `combine_subject`. Variables are hoisted and will hold last value(*function*) and will not have `.push`

Comment: _that is working but it is not working_ Huh??

Comment: r.i.p english..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The code shown doesn't do anything other than create a function, throw it away, and replace it with `[]`. If you were to try to call `combine_subject()`, it would fail because arrays can't be called. Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Fast forward: Change the name of the function or the array.

Next time, please invest the least of efforts into debugging before posting also work on your English bud.

Comment: I upvoted since you're right, but will also suggest that you'll show the OP what they need to do since they are obviously having problem understanding some basic things

Comment: That was in purpose, he has to invest some efforts by himself I believe.

Comment: Com'on, cut him some slack :)

Comment: I would love to, maybe being tough sometimes look cruel but it generates a better outcome in the long run. For instance, English is my fourth language and my teacher was really strict and tough with me to a point he demanded that I speak it as good as fellow Americans and it worked out for me for that I'm forever grateful to him. It was a tough year learning it from scratch but hey that's the way to go!